# Definir onClick en un BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Esto es una pregunta que he buscado por esta página, pero las soluciones que he ido encontrando, las he implementado, pero no me han funcionado, y aparecerán comentadas en el código, a ver si se me escapa algo o cualquier tontería pero no me sale.

Lo que quiero hacer es: Tengo un `ListView`, y cuando hago click en un elemento me muestre *"Has seleccionado XXXXX elemento"*, y ahora viene **lo que quiero implementar, el método onClick**, pues, **siempre** se me detiene la aplicación y no hay manera.

Importante: Trabajo con `Fragments`, mi `ListView` está en un `Fragment` y quiero que me lleve a otro `Fragment`.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private List<User> allUsers;

    private Context context;

    /*************
     * Constructor
     *****************/
    public UsersAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<User> data) {

        context = ctx;
        allUsers = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allUsers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        UserViewHolder holder = new UserViewHolder();

        final User user = allUsers.get(position);

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boxer_item, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (UserViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(user.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.icon);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// Lo que hago en este "if" es comparar lo que pulso con el nombre del elemento, para evitar una búsqueda más compleja. 

               if (user.getName() == "Ramon \nDekkers"){
                   Toast.makeText(context, "You ClickedFFFFFFFFFFFFEFEFF " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                  ////////////// ESTO ES LO QUE INTENTÉ YO /////////////////

                 //  Intent ramon = new Intent (context,Ramon_dekkers.class);
                //   ramon.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

               //   context.startActivity(ramon);

                   //v.getContext().startActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),Ramon_dekkers.class);
                 //  v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context,Ramon_dekkers.class));
 ``////////////// ESTO ES LO QUE INTENTÉ YO /////////////////``

               }
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
    private static class UserViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView name;
    }
}
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class y después si esta declarado en
>   el manifest.xml

Comment: Por si no me he expresado bien, quiero que al hacer click en un elemento de la lista, me lleve a un Fragment, ya está.

Comment: No tiene sentido, es un Fragment, no hay que declararlo, tampoco me deja, y me dejó ir a un Fragment sin declararlo en la misma App , pero este me pone eso..?

Comment: ¿ Es más fácil poner lo del método onClick en vez de aquí, en el Fragment donde cargo las imágenes y el texto de los elementos del ListView ?

Comment: No puedes hacer esto -> user.getName() == "Ramon \nDekkers"
si quieres comparar 2 variables Strings debes usar equals() -> user.getName().equals("Ramon \nDekkers")

Comment: Con getName == si que funcionaba , me parecia raro pero si que iba, de todas formas, lo implementare como dice. Respecto a lo que pido, no tiene una idea de como hacerlo? He probado mil formas y nada.... .__.

Comment: Voy a abrir una pregunta nueva especificando más a ver si así hay más respuestas porque es que no sé ni como hacerlo ya.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo  puedes hacerlo de varias formas y más sencillo. Ahorita se me viene a la mente 2 formas de hacerlo. Por cierto creo que es mejor opción tener un contenedor LinearLayout o Realtive y a ese hacerle esto:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Por ejemplo :

```
linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Porque no puedes setearlo directamente al ParentView.

Y con respecto al clic :

Puedes crear una Interface con un método  que pueda ser

```
onClick(View v)
```

y luego mandarla a llamar  y usarla como mejor se acomode.

2. Otra solución es crear un metodo en tu adapter que te regrese la pusición a la que le estas dando clic.

> ```
> listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
>             String item = adapter.getItem(position);
>
>  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position :"+position+"  ListItem : " +item ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         }
>    });
> ```

Y en tu adaptador puedes crear un metodo  que sea algo así: (

```
public String getItem(int position){
    return allUsers.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los fragments se gestionan de forma diferente a las actividades. En el código que adjuntas, se realiza un startAcivity al cual le deberías pasar una actividad, de ahí que te diga que la actividad no está declarada en el manifest. Para mostrar un navegar a un fragment debes incluirlo con una transacción en el FragmentManager. Te adjunto un ejemplo extraído de la documentación oficial de Android Developers en el que se reemplaza un fragment existente por el nuevo al que queremos navegar:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

fuente: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html